# Pandas / Python remove duplicates based on specific row values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I am trying to remove duplicated based on multiple criteria:

1. Find duplicated in column `df['A']`
2. Check column `df['status']` and prioritize OK vs Open and Open vs Close
3. if we have a duplicate with same status pick the lates one based on `df['Col_1]`

df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['11', '11', '12', np.nan, '13', '13', '14', '14', '15'],
'Status' : ['OK','Close','Close','OK','OK','Open','Open','Open',np.nan],
'Col_1' :[2000, 2001, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2002, 2000, 2004, 2000]})
df

Expected output:

[image]

I have tried differente solutions like the links below (map or loc) but I am unable to find the correct way:

[Pandas : remove SOME duplicate values based on conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38584061/pandas-remove-some-duplicate-values-based-on-conditions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create ordered categorical for prioritize `Status`, then sorting per all columns, remove duplicates by first column `A` and last sorting index:

```
c = ['OK','Open','Close']
df['Status'] = pd.Categorical(df['Status'], ordered=True, categories=c)

df = df.sort_values(['A','Status','Col_1']).drop_duplicates('A').sort_index()
print (df)
     A Status  Col_1
0   11     OK   2000
2   12  Close   2000
3  NaN     OK   2000
4   13     OK   2000
6   14   Open   2000
8   15    NaN   2000
```

EDIT If need avoid `NaN`s are removed add helper column:

```
df['test'] = df['A'].isna().cumsum()

c = ['OK','Open','Close']
df['Status'] = pd.Categorical(df['Status'], ordered=True, categories=c)

df = (df.sort_values(['A','Status','Col_1', 'test'])
        .drop_duplicates(['A', 'test'])
        .sort_index())
```

Comment: Thank you very much and is there a way to keep all NaNs in column A if we have multiple NaNs?

Comment: I just realized that the code works fine a part from the dates which are not selected by the latest one

Comment: @Caiotru - Can you explain more?

Comment: @Caiotru - One idea - are dates strings? Or datetimes? Or numbers?

Comment: For example if I have 2 OKs with the same code I would like the latest date to be picked, I would like to keep = 'last' if they are in order

Comment: @Caiotru - Is possible change data sample for see problem? And also please test my solution if working with new data.