# Multiple Condition Duplicate Filter (maybe drop) Pandas DataFrame Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

For starters, I think these 2 questions are on the correct path, but do not exactly hit what I want.

[Pandas : remove SOME duplicate values based on conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38584061/pandas-remove-some-duplicate-values-based-on-conditions)

[How to conditionally remove duplicates from a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45907133/how-to-conditionally-remove-duplicates-from-a-pandas-dataframe)

I have a very large DataFrame made up of tickets. Each ticket has a few types of text fields. In some tickets, the 2 different types of text fields will have the same text. If this is the case, I use only the `DESCRIPTION` type. A sample DataFrame is as follows:

```
TICKETID    TYPE    TEXT
123 PROBLEMCODE I want to use description for this item because it is a duplicate
123 DESCRIPTION I want to use description for this item because it is a duplicate
123 CODE1       Other field
124 PROBLEMCODE I need both here
124 DESCRIPTION Because there are not duplicated
124 CODE1       Other field
125 PROBLEMCODE I need both here
125 DESCRIPTION I do not want to delete the above problem code because TICKETID is different
125 CODE1       This field is not super important but matches data and never know where problems arise
```

Basically, I want to examine each `TICKETID` as it's own entity. Compare the `PROBLEMCODE` and `DESCRIPTION` text; if equal, filter out the `PROBLEMCODE` row and keep description.

In my mind the pseudocode is:

```
For a given ticketID:
    if Type = PROBLEMCODE or DESCRIPTION
        if TEXT = TEXT
            DROP PROBLEMCODE
```

Obviously, looping through a dataframe this way is not efficient. Pandas has plenty to do this referenced in the questions posted earlier. I am just having trouble figuring out which combination of methods and assignments will accomplish this. I have tried:

```py
# to create a dup row
data['Dup'] = data.duplicated(subset=['TEXT'])
# Then groupby ticket?
data.groupby(['TICKETID'])

# somehow compare true and false, but I can only do that in order of index (down the frame). 

# I am 99% percent sure looking at the other questions there should be a one or two liner 
# something like this that can accomplish:

dataTest = data.loc[data.groupby(['TICKETID']) & (data['TYPE'] =='PROBLEMCODE' | 'DESCRIPTION')].duplicated(subset=['TEXT'])

# Then filter based on true false
```

My expected output for the sample case would only delete the TICKET=123 PROBLEMCODE row as follows:

```
TICKETID    TYPE    TEXT
123 DESCRIPTION I want to use description for this item because it is a duplicate
123 CODE1       Other field
124 PROBLEMCODE I need both here
124 DESCRIPTION Because there are not duplicated
124 CODE1       Other field
125 PROBLEMCODE I need both here
125 DESCRIPTION I do not want to delete the above problem code because TICKETID is different
125 CODE1       This field is not super important but matches data and never know where problems arise
```

Let me know if you need more info

Comment: hi,show us the sample of you expected output

Comment: See edit. It would only delete the 123 Problem code row

Comment: see my answer, but you want to check duplicates only between PROBLEMCODE and DESCRIPTION ?and leaves DESCRIPTION?

Comment: Yes, keep DESCRIPTION if for a given TICKETID has 2 duplicate text fields

Comment: Gimme a sec and I will test answer on main data

Comment: see my edits now

Comment: I think that 2nd one got it. It takes like an hour to test on main app, but I will accept and upvote once I get it on there and can check easy

Comment: i did edits again, code should work faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    df = pd.DataFrame(
        {
            'ticket':[123,123,123,124,124,124],
            'type':['PROBLEMCODE','DESCRIPTION','code1','PROBLEMCODE','DESCRIPTION','code1'],
            'text':[' I want to use description fo',' I want to use description fo','other',
             'another str','second one','other'],
    
        }
    )
    print(df)
       ticket         type                           text
    0     123  PROBLEMCODE   I want to use description fo
    1     123  DESCRIPTION   I want to use description fo
    2     123        code1                          other
    3     124  PROBLEMCODE                    another str
    4     124  DESCRIPTION                     second one
    5     124        code1                          other
    
    # you can see here in this df(duplicates), all duplicated rows for type == DESCRIPTION or PROBLEMCODE
    duplicates = df[
        (df.type.isin(['DESCRIPTION','PROBLEMCODE'])) &
        (df.duplicated(subset=['ticket','text'],keep=False))
    ]
    
    print(duplicates)
       ticket         type                           text
    0     123  PROBLEMCODE   I want to use description fo
    1     123  DESCRIPTION   I want to use description fo
    
# remove duplicates from main df (using index to improve time)

df = df.drop(duplicates.index.tolist())
print(df)

# now concat duplicates with df (without description and problemcode

result = pd.concat([
    duplicates[duplicates.type=='DESCRIPTION'],df
]).sort_values(by='ticket').reset_index(drop=True)
print(result)
       ticket         type                           text
0     123  DESCRIPTION   I want to use description fo
1     123        code1                          other
2     124  PROBLEMCODE                    another str
3     124  DESCRIPTION                     second one
4     124        code1                          other
```

For solution above, you will received output without duplicates for `DESCRIPTION` and `PROIBLEMCODE` when ticket and text are same